# How to extend from IdealRadio

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to extend from existing module IdealRadio to build my own module (inet.physicallayer.idealradio). I know how to extend in .ned configuration, but how should I mark the parent class in .h?
Currently I have:

```
#ifndef MYBASE_H_
#define MYBASE_H_

namespace mytry {

class MyBase : public IdealRadio {
public:
    MyBase();
    virtual ~MyBase();
};

} /* namespace mytry */

#endif /* MYBASE_H_ */
```

IDE points that IdealRadio is not a class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdealRadio` is a compound module and it doesn't have `C++` class.
By default `IdealRadio` consists of the following modules:

- `IsotropicAntenna`
- `IdealTransmitter`
- `IdealReceiver`

These modules have own `C++` classes and you may prepare a new `C++` class which inherit from one of them.